# bootstrap dropdown menu expand like a page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a big list and I would like to show them inside a dropdown menu. Since the number is large it is better that the menu can expand to right instead of only vertical listing. Are you aware of any jquery plugin to use please?

My requirement is like this, when the dropdown menu is clicked a popup window or menu is shown:

`A       C         E
  A1      C1        E1
  A2      C2        E2
  A3      C3        E3
B       D        F
  B1      D1        F1
  B2      D2        F2
  B3      D3        F3`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I guess what you need is a [MegaMenu](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=megamenu). But for now, here you go:

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */

a {text-decoration: none; display: block; color: #333; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 0 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
nav ul ul {display: none;}
nav ul li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #999; margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
nav ul ul li {display: inline-block; width: 49%;}
nav ul ul li a {border-radius: 0; border-width: 1px 0;}
nav > ul > li {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="open">
        <a href="">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 9</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 9</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Item 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 9</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Item 4</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 9</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Item 5</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 9</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Literally you can have anything inside the inner `<ul>` as per your need. I just tried this. You can try with `<div>` and change the things accordingly.